# Changing the main chart title using Lazy High Charts Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Max frustration. I've tried so many different ways of implementing :title and setTitle but I cannot seem to change the main title above the chart. Here is the example given on the gem's page

```
    @h = LazyHighCharts::HighChart.new('graph') do |f|
      f.options[:chart][:defaultSeriesType] = "area"
      f.series(:name=>'John', :data=>[3, 20, 3, 5, 4, 10, 12 ,3, 5,6,7,7,80,9,9])
      f.series(:name=>'Jane', :data=> [1, 3, 4, 3, 3, 5, 4,-46,7,8,8,9,9,0,0,9] )
    end
```

The closest I've come is removing the title by using `f.options[:title] = "Test Title"`

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

f.options[:title][:text] = "I heart pie"

Look at the default_options method in the HighChart class for the default_settings.